# Using list in SQL query to import data to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, import

I'm trying to run a select query in Excel that imports information from MSSQL Server. I also have a list of clients in .csv file. 
The goal is to only import the records of clients on the .csv list, but I can't get Excel to look at the list (it is imported to Sheet2). I keep getting the Invalid Object Name error.

I can't believe this cannot be done without VB, but tried examples from MS and other threads with no luck.

The basic query I'm using is:

```
SELECT 
"Clients"."cltCode", "Clients"."cltClientName"
FROM   "dbo"."Clients" "Clients"   
WHERE cltClientName IN ( SELECT * FROM [Sheet2!A:A])
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the VBA code you are using?

Comment: you can't use a single query to join across two sources like that.  You need to construct the "in" clause and then plug it into your main query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. You have to build the inclusion list ("IN" part) yourself in VBA, construct the query and refresh the data connection (or build command, run the query, loop through the results and populate target range/sheet)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
"Clients"."cltCode", "Clients"."cltClientName"
FROM   "dbo"."Clients" "Clients"   
WHERE cltClientName IN ( SELECT * FROM [Sheet2!A:A])
```

Specify the exact location of the data.

```
FROM [Sheets2!A2:C4]
```

Comment: Still the same: invalid object name. I get this even if I trim the whole query and only leave 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet2!A1:A10]'. I noticed that different types of connections have different options available. I've been using OLE DB Query. Can this be a reason?

Comment: As I noted above, you can't use a single query across two different datasources (SQL Server and Excel).